# how to remove content after .jpg by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var lochash = "#http://www.thepresidiumschool.com/news_image/102%20NRD_7420.jpg&lg=1&slide=0";
```

i want to remove or replace content after .jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `replace()` to replace 'jpg*' and everything after that with just 'jpg'.

```js
var lochash = "#http://www.thepresidiumschool.com/news_image/102%20NRD_7420.jpg&lg=1&slide=0";

var newlochash = lochash.replace(/jpg(.)+/,'jpg');

console.log(newlochash);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `substring` to remove everything after '.jpg'.

```js
var lochash = "#http://www.thepresidiumschool.com/news_image/102%20NRD_7420.jpg&lg=1&slide=0";

lochash = lochash.substring(0, lochash.indexOf('.jpg')+4);
console.log(lochash);
```